# How can I auto-update electron using hazel?

Tags: electron

I would like to know how to auto update electron using hazel.
I have successfully auto-updated macs.

On windows, the auto-update does not work.
The log on the windows local machine stated can not find squrrel.

In Github releases,
I have uploaded dmg, exe and blockmap.

The following is the main process and confirms autoupdate
The following is the code checking for auto-updates in the main process.

```
import Log from 'electron-log';
import { app, autoUpdater, dialog } from 'electron';

let isFirstRun = true;
const DIALOG_INTERVAL = 60; // minutes
const CHECK_INTERVAL = 5; // minutes
const url = process.env.AUTO_UPDATER_FEED_URL
  ? `${process.env.AUTO_UPDATER_FEED_URL}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`
  : undefined;

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => Log.info('autoUpdater.checkingForUpdate'));
autoUpdater.on('update-available', () => Log.info('autoUpdater.updateAvailable'));
autoUpdater.on('update-not-available', () => Log.info('autoUpdater.updateNotAvailable'));
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName, releaseDate, updateURL) => {
  Log.info(['autoUpdater.updateDownloaded'], event, releaseNotes, releaseName, releaseDate, updateURL, isFirstRun);

  showDialog(releaseName);
});

autoUpdater.on('error', (err) => {
  Log.error({ err });
});

const showDialog = (releaseName: string) => {
  dialog
    .showMessageBox({
      type: 'info',
      buttons: ['アップデート', '1時間後'],
      title: 'Update',
      message: `新しいバージョン ${releaseName} をダウンロードしました。再起動してアップデートしますか？`,
    })
    .then((v) => {
      if (v.response === 0) {
        autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          showDialog(releaseName);
        }, DIALOG_INTERVAL * 60 * 1000);
      }
    });
};

export const observeUpdates = () => {
  if (!url) {
    return;
  }
  autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url });

  updateVersion(false);

  setInterval(() => {
    updateVersion(false);
  }, CHECK_INTERVAL * 1000 * 60);
};

export const updateVersion = (forceUpdate: boolean) => {
  isFirstRun = forceUpdate;
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4535

you must have your app installed in your machine to use auto updater, so I am not sure if that's possible to test autoupdate in development. 

If you build the target and install, it might work.